# Submit a q's on SharePoint 2007 that directs it to an email address

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to have function that enables a users to submit a question on SharePoint 2007, the question is then sent as an email to a specfied user.

Is there any in built function in sharepoint that allows this or do need to code this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only way to do it without coding is to have a list with an alert me function to send the e-mail.

If you wanna code, you can use [SPUtility.SendEmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.sendemail.aspx) with an event receiver on your list to achieve the result you want